# Make the curve be a fractal curve like complex Brownian motion

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex, fractals

This is my curve

[image]

My `LaTeX` code is

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
%\pgfmathsetseed{666666}

\node (Koo) at (1.5,2) {$K_{\infty}$};
\node (S-) at (-0.6,5.1) {$S_-$};
\node (S+) at (0.6,4) {$S_+$};
\node (r) at (1.2,3) {$r$};
\node (l) at (-1.59,4.2) {$\ell$};
\node (e) at (0.2,6.2) {$e$};

\draw (0,0)node[right] {$A$} -- (2,6) node[right] {$B$} -- (-2,6) node[left] {$C$} -- (0,0) ;

%\draw[red,->, decorate, decoration={random steps, segment length=2cm, amplitude=2cm}]
\draw[red,->]
plot [smooth, tension=0.6] coordinates
{ (0,0.02) (0,0.35) (0.1,0.6) (-0.15,1) (0.1,1.1) (-0.2,1.25) (0.56,1.8)
  (-0.85,2.6)
  (0.98,3)
  (-1.39,4.2)
  (0.7,4.75) (0.2,6)
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

---

I want this curve moves like a complex Brownian motion,

so I add `decorate, decoration={random steps,segment length=2pt,amplitude=2pt}`
(the comment in the above code).

But no matter what the value of length and amplitude,
there is always a bug: **Dimension too large**.

---

I fix this by enlarging all coordinates in the above `LaTeX` Code,
and the following image is the result.

[image]

The notations A,B,C, ..., width of the curve, and the arrow of red curve are too small.

**Is it possible to make the curve be a fractal curve like complex Brownian motion?**

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Hello! @Mensch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not a perfect solution but maybe you can use it. You can make everything larger:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3, very thick, font=\huge]
    \pgfmathsetseed{666666}
    \node (Koo) at (1.5,2) {$K_{\infty}$};
    \node (S-) at (-0.6,5.1) {$S_-$};
    \node (S+) at (0.6,4) {$S_+$};
    \node (r) at (1.2,3) {$r$};
    \node (l) at (-1.59,4.2) {$\ell$};
    \node (e) at (0.2,6.2) {$e$};

    \draw (0,0) node[right] {$A$} -- (2,6) node[right] {$B$} -- (-2,6) node[left] {$C$} -- cycle;

    \draw[red,arrows={->[length=10pt]}, decorate, decoration={random steps, segment length=2pt, amplitude=2pt}]
        plot [smooth] coordinates {
            (0,0.02) (0,0.35) (0.1,0.6) (-0.15,1) (0.1,1.1) (-0.2,1.25) (0.56,1.8)
            (-0.85,2.6)
            (0.98,3)
            (-1.39,4.2)
            (0.7,4.75) (0.2,6)
        };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Fractal Curve]

Comment: Thanks! This fits my needs.